# What is $\int f(3y +3) dy$

Tags: integration

$fx $ continue at interval [1,30].
$\int fx dx $ from 6 to 30 = 30.

What is $\int f(3y +3) dy$ from 1 to 9 ?

What is y ? Is it fx? 
Then $\int f(3y +3) dy$ = $\int f(3fx +3) dfx$

Do i have to find the equation of fx?

Is fx a quadratic or even polinomial? How do i know it?

While the information i know $fx $ continue at interval [1,30].
$\int fx dx $ from 6 to 30 = 30.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to compute$$\int_1^9f(3x+3)\,\mathrm dx.$$Let $u=3x+3$ and $\mathrm du=3\mathrm dx$. Then\begin{align}\int_1^9f(3x+3)\,\mathrm dx&=\frac13\int_1^9f(3x+3)\,3\mathrm dx.\\&=\frac13\int_{3\times1+3}^{3\times9+3}f(u)\,\mathrm du\\&=\frac13\int_6^{30}f(u)\,\mathrm du\\&=10.\end{align}